# Get a redirect link for a NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am sending a request, than i get some redirect link. I don't want to open that link because its not exist, its only give me some token id .

Problem is , that i don't get the redirect delegate to be called .
I have added the delegate with :

than the request and the redirect delegates :

```
NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

Than request :

```
-(void)getAccessToken
{
    NSString *baseUrl=@"my url that is working on a browser";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
          //data is nil    
      }];


}

 //delegate
     - (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection
                 willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request
                redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse;
    {
        NSLog(@"***** %@",request); //NOT LOGGED 
        if (redirectResponse)
         {

         }
          else
          {

          }
            return request;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start the connection with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` then you are not setting a delegate and no delegate callback methods will be called.

If you want to use the delegate methods you need to start the connection with `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`.